# How to call a class method on a class attribute?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an Attribute class that has a list of students I want to show students with an average above ten, but how do I call a method on an attribute class?

```py
class Scores:
    students =[]
    def __init__(self, code, listScore=[]):
        self.Score = listScore
        self.code=code
        Scores.students.append(self)

    def add_Score(self):
        for i in range(3):
            d = input(f"Enter number {i+1} : ")
            self.Score.append(d)

    def pass__(self):
        for grade in self.Score:
            if int(grade) < 10:
                return False
        return True

    def Passed(self):
        for student in Scores.students:
            if self.pass__():
                return (f" Passed : {self.code}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to assign to `students`, no `Scores` needed. For more info, see: https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide